# lightning-carousel not working in EDGE browser

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am using lightning-carousel in **lwc** and it works perfectly in Chrome but not in EDGE browser. I have included a link to the playground that works in Chrome but not in EDGE. In EDGE, it would display all images on the first tab and other tabs are blank.

Any ideas how to fix this in EDGE?

Click the below in Chrome and EDGE browsers to see the difference:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/547415d731eb543f34a9c8c81cc72d3516902203/edit

Answer (score 1):

Not much can be done here to help you as this is most likely related to the browser or the components themselves, best contact salesofrce support.